# How to use lower_bound on vector of vectors?

Tags: c++, c++11, vector, comparison, std

I am relative new at C++ and I have little problem. I have vector and in that vector are vectors with 3 integers.

Inner vector represents like one person. 3 integers inside that inner vector represents distance from start, velocity and original index (because in input integers aren't sorted and in output I need to print original index not index in this sorted vector).

Now I have given some points representing distance from start and I need to find which person will be first at that point so I have been thinking that my first step would be that I would find closest person to the given point so basically I need to find lower_bound/upper_bound.

How can I use lower_bound if I want to find the lower_bound of first item in inner vectors? Or should I use struct/class instead of inner vectors?

Comment: Do you want to search through the outer vector to find the lower bound of the first item in each? Or something else?

Comment: @doctorlove Yes I want to search through the outer vector to find the lower bound of the first item in each inner vector

Comment: @Snip3r: Your question is really unclear. Please **edit your question** to improve it but don't comment it. Either add several sentences explaining your goal, or some [MCVE]. Read more about [std::lower_bound](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/lower_bound), it probably is not doing what you believe.

Comment: Is the outer vector properly partitioned? "The range `[first, last)` must be partitioned with respect to the expression `element < value` or `comp(element, value)`. A fully-sorted range meets this criterion.". Given that you don't know what `comp` to use, it likely isn't

Comment: @Caleth Yes my vector is sorted by first value of inner vector and I have  custom function to sort this but doesn't seem to work for lower_bound.

Answer (score 3):

You would use the version of [`std::lower_bound` which takes a custom comparator](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/lower_bound) (the versions marked "(2)" at the link); and you would write a comparator of vectors which compares vectors by their first item (or whatever other way you like).

Howerver:

- As @doctorlove points out, `std::lower_bound` doesn't compare the vectors to each other, it compares them to a given value (be it a vector or a scalar). So it's possible you actually want to do something else.
- It's usually not a good idea to keep fixed-length sequences of elements in `std::vector`'s. Have you considered [`std::array`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array)?
- It's very likely that your "vectors with 3 integers" actually stand for something else, e.g. points in a 3-dimensional geometric space; in which case, yes, they should be in some sort of class.

Comment: "in your case, it would be a vector with a single element" The value compared to can be anything, e.g. `std::lower_bound(outer.begin(), outer.end(), 42, [](auto & vec, int value) { return vec[0] < value; })`

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure that your inner things should be `std::vector`-s of 3 elements. 
I believe that they should [std::array](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array)-s of 3 elements (because you *know* that the size is 3 and won't change).

So you probably want to have

```
 typedef std::array<double,3> element_ty;
```

then use `std::vector<element_ty>`  and for the rest (your `lower_bound` point) do like in [einpoklum's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49135265/841108).

BTW, you probably want to use [std::min_element](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/min_element) with an explicit compare.

Maybe you want something like:

```
std::vector<element_ty> vec;
auto minit = 
    std::min_element(vec.begin(), vec.end(),
                     [](const element_ty& x, const element_ty&y) {
                        return x[0] < y[0]));
```

Comment: We don't really understand what the OP actually wants. This is an educated guess.